# do predictions using cntk checkpoint

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, cntk

These days, I have tried a model which implemented by cntk. But I can't find a way to predict new pic with trained model. 
The trained model saved as a checkpoint:

```
trainer.save_checkpoint(os.path.join(output_model_folder, "model_{}".format(best_epoch)))
```

Then I have gotten some files like:

[image]

So, I tried to load this model checkpoint like:

```
model = ct.load_model('../data/models/VGG13_majority/model_94')
```

the code above can run successfully. Then I tried

```
model.eval(image_data)
```

but I got an error:[image]

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   update   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

this time I have tried the method below:

```
model = ct.load_model('../data/models/VGG13_majority/model_94')
model.eval({model.arguments[0]: [final_image]})
```

then a new error raised:

[image]

Comment: You need to know the number of inputs that your model needs. Based on the error, it seems like your model takes in more than one input.

Comment: I think the model want me to provide the dependence of outputs?

Comment: `that the requested output(s) '********' depend on, have not been provided.`

Comment: The only dependency of the output is the input. Anyhow, i noticed that you saved the model from the checkpoint. By doing so, you actually saved the "ground_truth" input_variable too. i.e. the input_variable you provided to the loss function

Comment: And hence why its complaining about a missing input_variable

Comment: ok, I know what to do. I can save the model from a normal way. But, by the way, is there any solution can switch checkpoint model to normal model?

Comment: I amended my answer with some sample code, see if it helps. You can recover the original model from checkpoint, but its just more troublesome. Recommend that you save directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any C.Function.eval() you need to pass a dictionary as the argument.

So it will go something like this, assuming that you only have one input_variable into the model:

```
model = C.load_model()
model.eval({model.arguments[0]: image_data})
```

Anyhow, i noticed that you saved the model from the checkpoint. By doing so, you actually saved the "ground_truth" input_variable to the loss function too.

I would recommend next time that you saved the model directly. Usually the files from save_checkpoint is meant to be used in restore_from_checkpoint()

```
import cntk as C
from cntk.layers import Dense

model = Dense(10)(C.input_variable(1))
loss = C.binary_cross_entropy(model, C.input_variable(10))

trainer = C.Trainer(model, (loss,), [C.adam(model.parameters, 0.9, 0.9)])
trainer.save_checkpoint("hello")
model.save()  # used this to save the model directly

# to recover model from checkpoint use below
trainer.restore_from_checkpoint("hello")
original_model = trainer.model
print(trainer)
for i in trainer.model.arguments:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Glad that i could serve :)